# Update data using Linq in SQL Server database without assinging values to each property

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq

I would like to update a record on bases of simple update Linq query but the problem is I don't want to assign values to each property.

Here is what I have to do every time that I want to update some recorders

```
var frm = db.MYTable.Where(s => s.Code == code).FirstOrDefault();
frm.Name = TxtName.Text;
frm.Code = TxtCode.Text;
frm.Mno = Convert.ToInt32(TxtMno.Text);
db.SaveChanges();
```

What I want is instead of using this way because some of my tables will have more than 50 columns, I would like to give a context/model context having values to set values in the database.

Comment: Do you have `code` as a property in `fmr`.. because I can see in `Where` clause you used `Code` instead of `code`

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar yes Code is a property in frm

Comment: You want pass object instead of set every changed properties?

Comment: @AmirNorouzpour yes

Comment: then `frm.code = TxtCode.Text;` gives you error.. because C# is case sensitive language

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar sorry about that but I think it was edited by someone.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, other than it seems to be "I want to write code without writing code" - not really sure how you're going to achieve that; you want to have some magic object that is already full of the data you want to save, and you want to hand it to the db and say "here; go through this and pick what what you want to save". About the closest thing I can think of to your goal is using a visual designer and data binding, but SOMETHING is still going to have to write the code that associated the txtName.Text with the Name column in the db...

Comment: where is `TxtName.Text` and `TxtCode.Text` coming from?

Comment: ...even if you make your object with your Name property to hand to your db, you're still going to have to write code to get the text the user typed, into the Name property. Yes it's boring and crappy work writing the repetitive code that links UI items to data layer properties but you only have to do it once.. it's also something you can simplify by using a capable text editor (sublime is my favourite) that can put multiple cursors in a document and type on all of them at once - https://scotch.io/courses/getting-started-with-sublime-text/multi-cursor-editing

Comment: @CaiusJard appreciate the answer but VS17 already have some of the cool features and I have Insert and update in the same function so having to write     frm.Code = TxtCode.Text; is no issue but since I've written it once why do it again, that's all i need

Comment: Sublime's multi-cursor feature capability far exceeds the "hold down alt and make a rectangle selection" offered by VS2017

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can really recommend you look at is something like data binding, to connect your text boxes to your data objects so that typing in the textbox sets the data value, and the code for linking them up is written by the winforms designer instead of you:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/winforms

I don't normally post such answers that are merely a link to the docs but you've asked a short question that has a huge answer, and it doesn't make sense to replicate all of MSDN into stack overflow "in case MSDN goes down" - it's pretty reliably always going to be available until the technology is well phased out and dead